# Error creating a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, json, syntax-error

The line of code below, which I thought creates a javascript object, gives me the following error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

This is the line of code:

```
    var flyer2 = {&quot;id&quot;:20,&quot;img_url&quot;:&quot;http://images.awfbeat.com/48395b02-59e5-4e26-b7bc-8c603008c9c4&quot;,&quot;img_width&quot;:0,&quot;img_height&quot;:0,&quot;popularity&quot;:0,&quot;color&quot;:&quot;#67c547&quot;,&quot;tag&quot;:&quot;Jul 10&quot;,&quot;category&quot;:&quot;festivals&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Darth Vader\\\u0027s \\\&quot;Annihilator\\\&quot;&quot;,&quot;title_slug&quot;:&quot;darth-vader-s-annihilator-&quot;,&quot;performer&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;performer_sort&quot;:&quot;xxxx&quot;,&quot;posted&quot;:&quot;2012-03-11 04:09:20.0&quot;,&quot;facebook_event_id&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;venue_postal&quot;:&quot;90802&quot;,&quot;venue_name&quot;:&quot; Aquarium of the Pacific&quot;,&quot;venue_street&quot;:&quot;100 Aquarium Way&quot;,&quot;venue_city&quot;:&quot;Los Angeles&quot;,&quot;venue_region_abbr&quot;:&quot;CA&quot;,&quot;venue_lat&quot;:&quot;33.762226&quot;,&quot;venue_lng&quot;:&quot;-118.19686&quot;,&quot;needs_info&quot;:false};
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `&quot;` in your real code...? At least change it to `"`.

Comment: As @rob-w said, remove your &quot;. Here you have a usefull tool to validate your JSON data: [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You're html-encoding the quotes.

Not 100% sure, but I guess the ampersand is parsed as the **bitwise and** operator, semicolons as line end symbols.

Answer (score 1):

If this is serverside code then
the solution is:

```
 var flyer2 = "{"\""id"\"":20,"\""img_url"\"":"\""http://images.awfbeat.com/48395b02-59e5-4e26-b7bc-8c603008c9c4"\"","\""img_width"\"":0,"\""img_height"\"":0,"\""popularity"\"":0,"\""color"\"":"\""#67c547"\"","\""tag"\"":"\""Jul 10"\"","\""category"\"":"\""festivals"\"","\""title"\"":"\""Darth Vader\\\u0027s \\\"\""Annihilator\\\"\"""\"","\""title_slug"\"":"\""darth-vader-s-annihilator-"\"","\""performer"\"":"\"""\"","\""performer_sort"\"":"\""xxxx"\"","\""posted"\"":"\""2012-03-11 04:09:20.0"\"","\""facebook_event_id"\"":"\"""\"","\""venue_postal"\"":"\""90802"\"","\""venue_name"\"":"\"" Aquarium of the Pacific"\"","\""venue_street"\"":"\""100 Aquarium Way"\"","\""venue_city"\"":"\""Los Angeles"\"","\""venue_region_abbr"\"":"\""CA"\"","\""venue_lat"\"":"\""33.762226"\"","\""venue_lng"\"":"\""-118.19686"\"","\""needs_info"\"":false}";
```

else

```
var flyer2 = {"id":20,"img_url":"http://images.awfbeat.com/48395b02-59e5-4e26-b7bc-8c603008c9c4","img_width":0,"img_height":0,"popularity":0,"color":"#67c547","tag":"Jul 10","category":"festivals","title":"Darth Vader\\\u0027s \\\"Annihilator\\\"","title_slug":"darth-vader-s-annihilator-","performer":"","performer_sort":"xxxx","posted":"2012-03-11 04:09:20.0","facebook_event_id":"","venue_postal":"90802","venue_name":" Aquarium of the Pacific","venue_street":"100 Aquarium Way","venue_city":"Los Angeles","venue_region_abbr":"CA","venue_lat":"33.762226","venue_lng":"-118.19686","needs_info":false};
```

or else use single quota.